# When is PHP 5.4 end of life?

Tags: php

PHP 5.6 stable was released on 28 Aug. 2014. When is PHP 5.4 end-of-life date? I couldn't find anything about it in PHP website. It is important to me because I have to decide whether I have to upgrade old sites or not. Many hosting providers are still providing services with PHP 5.3 or 5.4. Is there any talk or decision about this date in PHP community?

Comment: there is a table in here . http://php.net/supported-versions.php .and you can find more useful information.

Comment: @jamlee Kudos to you. Would you please repost this as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP 5.4 end-of-life date is September 14, 2015.

You can find this information on the PHP site, [here](http://php.net/supported-versions.php).

Answer (score 8):

Beside the release cycle of PHP, you should also consider the life cycle of the base OS you are using.

As an example, PHP 5.3 on RHEL/CentOS 6 will be supported with security fixes by RedHat/CentOS until [Nov 30, 2020](http://wiki.centos.org/About/Product#fndef-a91b3c0c287c782f9af063daff9e64b566d648c7-2).

Since even today, many PHP apps need something newer than 5.3, this is of limited use for newer versions of stuff like Typo3 etc. but what's running on 5.3 can do so until 2020.

Answer (score 4):

When PHP 5.4.33 was released on 18 Sep 2014, the following was [announced](https://php.net/archive/2014.php#id2014-09-18-2):

> This release is the last planned release that contains regular
>   bugfixes. All the consequent releases will contain only
>   security-relevant fixes, for the term of one year.

With simple math, one year ahead is **September 2015**.

Answer (score 3):

In the [release announcement of PHP 5.3.29](http://php.net/archive/2014.php#id2014-08-14-1), it was mentioned that PHP 5.4 is *at least* supported to 2015:

> All PHP 5.3 users are encouraged to upgrade to the current stable
>   version of PHP 5.5 or previous stable version of PHP 5.4, which are
>   supported till at least 2016 and 2015 respectively.